# OAuth2 WebAPI Token remove .issued and .expires

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, owin

The token is always returned following information:

```
{
  "access_token": ".....",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 1199,
  "custom_info1": ".....",
  "custom_info2": "....",
  ".expires": "Fri, 13 Nov 2015 20:24:06 GMT",
  ".issued": "Fri, 13 Nov 2015 20:04:06 GMT"
}
```

Can we remove the .expires and .issued information?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It helps the consuming client know that when they are supposed to logout the user from the system and re authenticate them.

Comment: @Jamshaid, I agreed this is the standard result for REST API. Recently my company hired external security film to do penetration testing, and they found that the API return expires and issues are dangerous, leaking the token period to attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can remove them by override the TokenEndpointResponse method

```
public override Task TokenEndpointResponse(OAuthTokenEndpointResponseContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
         if (property.Key != ".issued" && property.Key != ".expires")
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }
        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
```